# Getting value of PHP created ckeditor with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor

I'm using PHP to create ckeditori in my view , I am using a mvc framework so it's the easiest way to go.

In my controller:

```
$data['text_editor'] = array(
    'ckfinder' => array( 'path'    =>    './assests/ck/ckfinder'),
    'id'       =>     'text', 
    'path'     =>    './assests/ck/ckeditor',
    'config'   => array(
    'toolbar' =>     "Full",    
    'filebrowserImageUploadUrl' => base_url().'baseController/ckupload'             )
);
$this->load->view('view' , $data ) ;
```

in view :

```
<textarea name="text" id="text" ></textarea>

<?php
echo display_ckeditor($text_editor);
?>
```

Now I want to get value of editor with js:

```
function get_value(){
  alert(CKEDITOR.instances['text'].getData());
}
```

I've also tried:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['text_editor'].getData()
```

But it doesn't work and I got this error:

```
TypeError: CKEDITOR.instances.text is undefined
alert(CKEDITOR.instances['text'].getData());
```

Comment: if you're setting the id/name of the ck box to be `text`, shouldn't you be using `'text'` in your CKEDITOR.instances array lookups as well? Nowhere in your html is there a `text_editor`

Comment: @MarcB as i said i've tried that

Comment: well, you could do some basic debugging: `console.log(CKEDITOR.instances)`. That'd probably solve this FAR quicker than hoping someone will randomly guess what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.text.getData();
```

If it doesn't, my guess is that you're probably trying to run the get_value function before the instance is created, which would result in an `undefined` error.

Maybe try:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function() {
  CKEDITOR.instances.text.getData();
});
```